# Network folders visible

Tags: windows-10, networking, network-shares

I want to be able to access my two windows 10 devices from each other in my local network.
Unfortunately I still lack a little knowledge.

My laptop was visible instantly from my windows tablet. And I was able to view and access all folders and files on the laptop.

The problem is, my tablet was not visible from the beginning. It is now, but I can not see any folders when I try to access it from my laptop.

Do I have to manually make each folder available?
Or can I make the whole device visible?

Comment: For starters, check these things:    1. Make sure Network Discovery and File / Print Sharing are enabled on both computers.   
 2. Make sure password protected sharing is enabled both computers.   
 3. Make sure both computers are in the same WORKGROUP.    
 4. Make sure Wireless connections are Private, not Public.

Comment: Thanks, I confirmed that. My main issue is, I do not want to make each folder separately available. I want all folders and files  to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

To share a folder in your local network, go to *Properties* of the folder, click on *Share*, add `Everyone`, and give all permissions to add or remove fille for that share: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: `Everyone` really shouldn't be given access to a network share - instead, the user accessing the share should be provided permissions.

Answer (score -1):

I found [this checklist](https://www.technorms.com/82014/computer-not-showing-up-on-network) helpful. It's the most complete list of possible solutions I could find.

(Note: In my case only turning on the old SMB 1.0 sharing in Windows Features finally helped (step 11), which could be a security risk that may be acceptable to take for very small networks, e.g. at home behind a firewall.)

Comment: **SMB v1 should _never_ be enabled** as it's been actively exploited daily for years - all OSes have supported SMBv2 since at least 2010 _(if a share works with SMBv1 enabled, but not with it disabled, the issue is user permissions aren't correctly configured since SMBv2 enables encrypted authentication by default - e.g. resolve the issue by correctly configuring authentication/access permissions)_

Comment: It's surely a bit desperate, but I wouldn't use the word "never". I have tried for hours to make it work and in my little private network I can live with the shortcomings of SMB v1. If you have a more exhaustive list of things I can try, then I'm curious...

Comment: SMBv1 is dangerous to have enabled, so if you value your data, immediately disable it - as I previously stated, it's been exploited _daily_ for something like five years at this point. I also explained why SMBv1 would work and SMBv2 would not. Perhaps you could create a question with details to get some help with the issue your having.

Comment: It's a calculated risk having in enabled in a tiny 2-3 computers network behind a firewall. I wouldn't consider enabiling in in larger networks though. I don't have time to spend days and weeks of work only to be able to see my other computers under Network. If the recommended network stack is that brittle, I just won't use it. I encountered this problem since several Windows versions occasionally and I know from friends who also hab the problem. If you know a fool-proof solution to this, then go ahead and provide an answer. Until then, it motivates me to make backups on a more regular basis.

Comment: Provide an answer to what? The OP's issue isn't with enabling SMBv1, that was your answer. I stated what your issue is in my first comment, as well as how to resolve it.

Comment: My answer was the reference to the link with the checklist, which is the most exhaustive I could find on the internet. I'll change the answer to clarify this.

Comment: If you could please copy/paste the content from the checklist into your answer via quote markdown `>`, that would be preferable to only providing a link, since there's no way to guarantee the link will still exist in 1yr, 5yrs, 10yrs, etc., whereas this question and answer will always exist on StackExchange. With the current edit, if this is done, I'll remove my downvote

Comment: I'm not so sure about copyright implications, rather made a snapshot with the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.technorms.com/82014/computer-not-showing-up-on-network

Comment: Have you ever come across copyright concerns on StackExchange or any Meta pages from quoting content with quote markdown that's accompanied by a link to the source? Why do you believe the source link you provided has copyrighted content?

Comment: Where I come from, quoting parts of a text is ok, if referenced correctly, but not copying the whole thing.

Comment: If posting an answer on StackExchange, simply linking to an answer as an answer is not acceptable for the reason I previously stated _(if wishing to only do so, commenting, in lieu of posting an answer, would be more amenable)_. You may wish to reference the help section on Answers, specifically [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing).